# How to index dynamically N-dimensions by using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

When I input a value of N, a N-dimensional matrix is generated automatically. I want to index automatically the N-dimensional matrix based on the value of N.

For example, if the dimension of the matrix A is 3:

```
temp = A[a + 1, a + 2, a + 3]
```

If it is 4:

```
temp = A[a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4]
```

Because my entire code generates many matrices with various dimenstions through the value of N, I seek ways that meet my needs.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean square matrices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply build a tuple containing the required index, and use that tuple to index into `temp`.